# Кнопка копировать

Tags: javascript

Есть код для кнопки "Копировать", с текстом  на кнопке "Копировать", после нажатия должен писать "Скопировано". Есть 10 таких кнопок на странице допустим, 1-я работает корректно, но остальные уже не меняются на "Скопировано". В чём проблема?

```js
const copyToClipbBoard = () => {
  const copyContent = document.querySelector("code");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyContent.innerText);
}

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  copyToClipbBoard();

  button.innerText = "Скопировано";

  setTimeout(() => {
    button.innerText = "Копировать";
  }, 700);
})
```

Comment: `querySelector` берёт первый подходящий по условию элемент из DOM.  А вот `querySelectorAll` берёт все подходящие. но с ними необходимо работать уже в цикле, перебирая все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код написан под работу только с одной кнопкой.

Предлагаю переписать под функцию и на кнопки повесить `onclick` атрибут для удобства:

```js
const _forCopy = document.createElement('textarea');
_forCopy.style.cssText = 'opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; z-index: -1; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transform: transalte(-100%, -100%);';
document.body.append(_forCopy);

function CopyFromElem(elem, btn) {
  elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
  btn = typeof btn === 'string' ? document.querySelector(btn) : btn;
  
  if(!elem) return false;
  
  const btnText = btn.innerHTML;
  const text = elem.value ? elem.value : elem.innerHTML;
  
  if(text.length > 0) {
    _forCopy.value = text;
    _forCopy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    
    if(btn) {
      btn.style.color = 'green';
      btn.innerHTML = 'Скопировано!';
    }
  } else {  
    if(btn) {
      btn.style.color = 'red';
      btn.innerHTML = 'Упс, нечего копировать';
    }
  }
  
  if(btn) setTimeout(() => {
    btn.style.color = '';
    btn.innerHTML = btnText;
  }, 700);
}
```

```html
<pre id="pre">Тут можно скопировать код</pre>
<br>
<button onclick="CopyFromElem('#pre', this)">Копировать</button>
<hr>
<div id="div">Из дива</div>
<br>
<button onclick="CopyFromElem('#div', this)">Копировать</button>
<hr>
<textarea id="textarea">Даже из textarea</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="CopyFromElem('#textarea', this)">Копировать</button>
```

В функцию `CopyFromElem(elem, btn)` первым параметром передаём элемент или селектор откуда будет копироваться текст, вторым (необязательный) передаём элемент или селектор, в который будет добавляться "текст-статус" выполненого действия.